# Use part of an URL under other domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a webshop as part of a website on an Apache server that can be reached on an URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/webshop
```

There are a bunch of URLs that are derived from this URL, for e.g.:

```
http://www.example.com/webshop/tops/
http://www.example.com/webshop/tops/sweatshirts
http://www.example.com/webshop/tops/t-shirts
http://www.example.com/webshop/bottoms/
http://www.example.com/webshop/bottoms/shorts
http://www.example.com/webshop/bottoms/jeans
...
```

I would like to register a domain (for e.g.: examplewebshop.com) and configure it for the webshop part of the website URL, so it is able to show the contents of http://www.example.com/webshop/ without redirecting. So for e.g. these:

```
http://www.example.com/webshop/tops/sweatshirts
http://www.example.com/webshop/bottoms/shorts
```

could be reached under the URL of

```
http://www.examplewebshop.com/tops/sweatshirts
http://www.examplewebshop.com/bottoms/shorts
```

as well.

Can this be achieved?
If yes, is it only .htaccess + RewriteRules, or something else?

Comment: In your `www.examplewebshop.com` VirtualHost, you can setup RewriteRules to redirect to `www.example.com/webshop`.  No need for htaccess, unless you have no access to the configuration file (most hosting site for example).  No wait, you said without redirecting...  Ok so you have to setup a proxy then.  `RewriteRules` with option `[P]` can work, `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` are simpler since you do not have complicated patterns to match.  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: @Nic3500, checked the link, thanks! Can you add your comment (perhaps with an example of how you might solve this) as an answer?